# Characterization of the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-equations

> **Problem (from Rudin):** 
>   Suppose $f(x)f(y) = f(x+y)$ for all real $x$ and $y$. 
>   Assuming that $f$ is differentiable and not zero, prove that $f(x) = e^{cx}$ where $c$ is a constant.

I've shown that $f > 0$, and that $f(0) = 1$. I need help showing that $f'(x) = f(x)$. When I apply the product rule, I get $$f'(x) = f'(x+0) = (f(x)f(0))' = f'(x)f(0) + f(x)f'(0),$$ but I don't know where to go from there.

Answer (score 1):

Fix $x$. Since
\begin{align}
f(x+y)=f(x)f(y)
\end{align}
then differentiating with respect to $y$ yields
\begin{align}
f'(x+y)=f(x)f'(y).
\end{align}
Now set $y =0$ and you get
\begin{align}
f'(x)=f'(0)f(x).
\end{align}

Comment: How do you know that $f'(0) = 1$?

Comment: Why do you need it to be 1?

Comment: Oh, nevermind. I see now that $c = f'(0)$

Comment: @N.Cain Correct.